# how to get the asserted value in Julia?

Tags: types, julia, type-assertion

```
struct MyType

end


struct MyType2
 attr::MyType
end
```

My question is: if there is anyway to get `attr` within `MyType`. I know there is subtypes() that gives all subtypes of a type, I need something like this but for type assertion.

Comment: Do you mean to know the fields of a given type? If so, `fieldnames(MyType2)` list al the fields of the `MyType2` type

Comment: `attr` is a field of `MyType2`, not of `MyType`. There is no relationship between those two types, except that their names are similar. They are not sub and supertypes of each other. So what does your question mean?

Comment: I believe what they mean is: given a type, they want to know what variables have been asserted to be that type. So for example, if I have `x::Int` in my code, then they want a function (or more likely a macro) that could take `Int` as an argument and return `x` (and whatever other variables are asserted to be `Int`s).

Comment: This probably requires you to do static analysis of some sort on the code yourself, I don't think there's an inbuilt function to do this. What is your usecase for this, what do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a new type hierarchy, then you want something like this:

```
abstract type MyAbstractType end

struct MyType <: MyAbstractType
    #include the fields you want MyType to have
end
```

Then you can call:

```
julia> supertype(MyType)
MyAbstractType
```

See the documentation for more examples: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/

In Julia, concrete types (i.e. types that can actually be instantiated and store other variables) cannot inherit from other concrete types. They can only inherit from abstract types, which cannot be instantiated but simply let you organize concrete types into some hierarchy.